# Jest Test Case Reporting

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, lwc-jest

Is there a way to publish Jest test case results?

i.e., instead of only having test cases run locally on a single developers machine, is there a way to upload them to your org or github to be run in an adhoc manner by anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the major git services, like GitHub, and CI/CD services, like CircleCI, have a way to run tests and store those results on the server itself. In this manner, it's possible for any authorized user to see previous builds, the success/fail status, and even code coverage results. For example, you could have Jest run all tests, and those results will be available to see from the build status screen. Or, you can use sfdx's `force apex test run` command to get a full result of errors and code coverage for Apex--and even block the build from deploying if there are any fatal errors, like compilation or unit test failures. However, each system is unique, so you'll need to read your platform's online documentation for specific details. Some services have limited build times, or charge extra for these features, so I recommend you shop around before committing (pun intended).